# Git does not work behind a special connection and proxy

Tags: git, svn, ubuntu, proxy

I use wired connection and behind a public proxy (method: automatic; configuration URL: http://frankiz.xxx.fr/proxy.pac) at home.

To make `sudo get-apt` and `svn` work, the technicians have added the following code in `/etc/subversion/servers`:

```
[global]
http-proxy-host = kuzh.xxx.fr
http-proxy-port = 8080
```

And in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://kuzh.xxx.fr:8080/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://kuzh.xxx.fr:8080/";
```

But the `git` as follows, which works well elsewhere, does not work at home:

```
...@ubuntu$ git clone MyAccount@OurDomain:/users/.../AnotherAccount/git/work
Cloning into work...
ssh: connect to host OurDomain port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use Git's HTTP transport if you're going to use a HTTP proxy, or a SOCKS proxy if you're going to use the SSH transport. It's probably easiest if you ask the guy who set up that HTTP stuff for SVN if he can set up the same thing for Git+SSH (I'm sure he's technically able, but company policy may prevent him from doing so).

It's possible to host Git on HTTP. Here's a brief [setup guide](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html) with the stuff you need to have done to get the server up and running. Client-side configuration is done by setting the `http_proxy` and/or `https_proxy` environment variables, or setting [the right bits](http://acassis.wordpress.com/2008/10/27/using-git-behind-proxy/) in git config.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... the technical guy is on holiday and will be back next week...

Answer (score 0):

Git has it's own way of configuring a proxy server, like this:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

Or alternatively, edit your `.gitconfig` or the projects `.git/config` file manually to add a section like this:

```
[http]
    proxy = http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. I simply overlooked that, because the post mentions the Subversion configuration and tagged Subversion.. Thanks for pointing out, I rewrote my answer.